# Adapter from Class in Fragments

Tags: listview, android-fragments, adapter

I am loading a database with multiple Strings into a ListView in Android
It works fine until I tried to get the same code in to my Fragments project

I have a Class that I use to populate my adapter, and it's not working in Fragments
The only problem is this line of code

```
MyAdapter = new AdapterClass (this);
```

This is the whole fragment code

```
public class Fragment_10 extends Fragment {


private ClassAdapter MyAdapter;
private ListView lv;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){


     View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_10, container, false);
     ParseObject.registerSubclass(MyClass.class);

    lv = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list);  


              lv.setClickable(false);
        MyAdapter = new ClassAdapter (this);
        MyAdapter.loadObjects();
        lv.setAdapter(favoritesAdapter);

    return V;
}
```